# Calculate the rect of a segment

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I calculate the rect of a segment?

For example:

This segment:

```
A(0,8) B(4,0)
```

So with a *"magic"* formula I would get this result:

```
f(x) = -8/4 * x + 8
```

(for this case I used this `f(x) = -1 * (Ay/Bx) * X + Ay` but only seems to work if Ay = 0 and Bx = 0)

Comment: what is a rect?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh He means a "straight line."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point and a direction, you can determine the line which passes along them.

More precisely, given the points $A$ and $B$, where $A\neq B$, the corresponding line is given by:
\begin{align*}
L(t) = A + t(B - A)
\end{align*}

At the present case, one has that $A = (0,8)$ and $B = (4,0)$. Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
L(t) = (0,8) + t(4,-8) = (4t, 8 - 8t)
\end{align*}

In the particular case where we work with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we can eliminate the parameter $t$:
\begin{align*}
(x,y) = (4t, 8 - 8t) \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = 4t\\\\
y = 8 - 8t
\end{cases} \Rightarrow y = 8 - 2x
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!